# Replacing a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, replace, overriding, tampermonkey

There is a JavaScript file attached to the page's source and I am wanting to edit and overwrite a function from it using TamperMonkey so I can change what the function does, is this possible?
This is the function:

```
function handleNext () {
        switch(curIndex){
        case 0:
            startLoading();
            $.getJSON(API_URL + getSubdomain() + "/names", function(res) {
                if(res.A == true) {
                    moveToSection($("#section-name-links"), $("#section-user-prefrences"));
                } else {
                    finishLoading();
                    displayError("Incorrect");
                }

            }).fail(function() {
                finishLoading();
                displayError("An error occured");
            });
            break;
        case 1:
            startLoading();
            var success = true;
            if($("#prefrences input[name=name]").val() == ""){
                displayError("Please enter your name");
                success = false;
            }
            if($("#section-user-prefrences input[surname=surname]").size() > 0 && 
                $("#section-user-prefrences input[surname=surname]:checked").size() == 0){
                displayError("Please enter your last name");
                success = false;
            }
            if(!success){
                finishLoading();
                return;
            }
            var rewardid = $("#section-user-prefrences input[name=reward]:checked").val();
            $.post(API_URL + getSubdomain() + "/names", {
                nameid: namesid || -1,
                username: $("#section-user-prefrences input[name=name]").val()
            }, function(res) {
                moveToSection($("#section-user-prefrences"), $("#section-thank-you"));
                $("#continue").hide();
            }).fail(function() {
                finishLoading();
                displayError("An error occured");
            });

            break;
        }
    }
```

And what I'm aiming to do is change the function to something along the lines of:

```
    function handleNext () {
        switch(curIndex){
        case 0:
            startLoading();

                    moveToSection($("#section-name-links"), $("#section-user-prefrences"));

            }).fail(function() {
                finishLoading();
                displayError("An error occured");
            });
            break;
        case 1:
            startLoading();
            var success = true;
            if(!success){
                finishLoading();
                return;
            }

            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want us to help you *hack* a website? Really?

Comment: But tampermonkey isn't really hacking as it doesn't affect anyone else.

Comment: If the said function is global, you can overwrite it as `window.handleNext = function() {}` or simply `handleNext = function() {}` (without a preceding `var`)

Comment: @techfoobar thanks for the reply and it didn't work the main code is still taking action when I click continue :\

Comment: You need to rebind the event on the specific element as well so that it calls your version rather than the old one.